# Is Reactivity in Meteor affected by the fields selected in the query?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

If my UI depends on

```
MyCollection.find({_id: "..."})
```

I know that it triggers the reactivity whenever any field in that document changes. But if I just select one field from that document:

```
MyCollection.find({_id: "..."}, {fields: { MyAttr: 1 }})
```

Does reactivity get triggered for any change to the document with that _id, or does it only get triggered for changes to the `MyAttr` field of that document?

Comment: `find` return a cursor and cursor is reactive

Comment: @ThaiTran, I know it's reactive, it's more of a question of what it reacts to. Will it react to any change in that document, or only changes in that field?

Comment: the question makes no sense, because it's not clear.. Thai Tran said that the whole returned cursor is reactive, so what is not clear?

Comment: The short answer is NOT: it is only reactive on the fields you output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a simple test to determine this:

test.html:

```
<template name="test">
  {{ #if Template.subscriptionsReady }}
    {{ GetMyAttr }}
  {{ /if }}
</template>
```

test.js:

```
Template.test.helpers({
  GetMyAttr: function() {
    console.log('called GetMyAttr');
    return MyCollection.findOne({_id: "jpBLBgCyEi3XpicxF"}).MyAttr;
  }
});

Template.test.onCreated(function() {
  this.subscribe("my_collection");
});
```

Now, when I manually update `MyOtherAttr` on the "jpBLBgCyEi3XpicxF" document, `called GetMyAttr` is logged to the console. But if I change the find statement to:

```
return MyCollection.findOne({_id: "jpBLBgCyEi3XpicxF"}, {fields: {MyAttr: 1}}).MyAttr;
```

Then updating the `MyOtherAttr` on the "jpBLBgCyEi3XpicxF" document
 does not cause `called GetMyAttr` to be printed.

> **Conclusion: Cursors react only to changes in the data returned in those cursors.**

In retrospect, this seems obvious that it should work that way. I think this is a good reason to use the `{fields: {}}` part of the query more often, to reduce unnecessary reactivity.

Comment: sorry I misinterpreted your original question! You are absolutely correct.